# How to wrap additional links with div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapall

I am trying to wrap links in a div if the there is more than 4 links in the parent div with jQuery:

```html
<div class="acclinks">
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
  <a href="#">6</a>
  <a href="#">7</a>
  <a href="#">8</a>
</div>
```

I wanted to be like this:

```html
<div class="acclinks">
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <div class="more">
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">7</a>
    <a href="#">8</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean wrap the fifth link and up in a div but leave the first four how they are.

Comment: Show html result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector, to select element with index great that specific number. Then use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) to wrap selected elements in new html.

```
$(".acclinks a:gt(3)").wrapAll("<div class='more'></div>");
```

```js
$(".acclinks a:gt(3)").wrapAll("<div class='more'></div>");
```

```css
.more { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="acclinks">
   <a href="#">1</a>
   <a href="#">2</a>
   <a href="#">3</a>
   <a href="#">4</a>
   <a href="#">5</a>
   <a href="#">6</a>
   <a href="#">7</a>
   <a href="#">8</a>
</div>
```